# Combining discrete variable and continuous variables in a linear model framework

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm trying to assess the influence of temperature, geography and larvae connectivity on the genetic structure (Fst values) of a marine species.

I used a linear regression framework, which examine the correlation between the genetic variation (FST) and temperature/geography (GEO) values.

For instance giving the following command in R:

```
lm(Fst ~ GEO + TEMP, data)
```

On the other side, I have larvae connectivity (CO) values that I want to include in the model I build.

For instance the model would be:

```
lm(Fst ~ GEO + TEMP + CO)
```

However, the connectivity values are either 0 (not connected) or 1 (connected).
These values follow more a logistic regression than a linear one.

Then, how could I include these connectivity values test in my linear model with temperature and geography?

When I tested `lm(Fst ~ CO)`, the residuals seems correct.

Could I trust the results and use a simple linear regression model for these data?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is effectively a duplicate, or at least one worth linking to another question, but I'm having trouble turning anything up.

Answer (score 2):

There's no issue whatever in having a 0/1 variable on the right hand side of your model (i.e. as a predictor/"independent variable"/covariate). Binary variables and factors more generally are common in regression models.

That doesn't make it "logistic"; you might use a logistic model if you had a 0/1 variable on the *left hand side* of the model (as a response/"dependent variable").

[As to whether you can "trust the results", that depends on other things than whether there's a 0/1 variable in your model.]

Answer (score 0):

In the second model, when you apply ordinary linear squares (OLS) regression, the binary variable `CO` is *dummy coded*: $X$ will either take the value $0$ or $1$.

From the point of view of linear algebra, your second model will be as follows:

$$\Tiny \begin {bmatrix}  
Fst_1\\ Fst_2\\Fst_3\\\vdots\\ Fst_n
\end {bmatrix}  = \Tiny \begin {bmatrix}  
1&GEO_1&TEMP_1&CO_1\\ 1&GEO_2&TEMP2&CO_2\\1&GEO_3&TEMP_3&CO_3\\1&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\ 1&GEO_n&TEMP_n&CO_n
\end {bmatrix} \small \begin {bmatrix}  
\beta_0\\ \beta_1\\\beta_2\\ \beta_n
\end {bmatrix} $$

... Just like any other system. But while all the other variable values in the *model matrix* (i.e. $\small GEO$ and $\small TEMP$ are numeric, continuous realizations of random variables with typically a wide range of real values, $\small CO$ will be a bunch of zeros and ones depending on whether each particular *observation or subject* (remember that observations or subjects are points in the data cloud, and correspond to individual rows in the model matrix... I guess specimens of the marine species you are studying) is "connected" ($X=1$, or in our case, $\small CO_i=1$) or "not connected" ($\small CO_i=0$), whatever that means in your dataset. Effectively, then, $\beta_n$ acts like a switch (when $\small CO_i=0$, the switch is off, and we don't add any contribution from the coefficient of $\small CO$ (i.e. $\small \beta_n$); when $\small CO_i=1$ the effect of $\small \beta_n$ is added to the prediction).

Therefore, when $X=1$, we are just adding a constant to the intercept (or subtracting) - in effect, the intercept will be $\beta_0+\beta_n$, instead of just $\beta_0$.

As @Glen_b was explaining, in logistic regression the idea is completely unrelated: we are modelling a system where a number of regressors are trying to explain the *odds* of something happening or not happening, a binary outcome, on the left-hand side of the equation. On the LHS we have the $ln\,(odds)$ and on the RHS we have a system pretty much as above *with or without* dummy variables. We assume that the outcome ($Y=1$) follows a binomial distribution with probability $pi$, and come up with the *logit* function $ln(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi})$ for the LHS.